# how to tank with low level brewmaster monk

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I started playing WOW again and want to try out (Brewmaster) monk tanking. Currently at lvl 15, and I wonder how am I supposed to keep aggro at this level (and coming levels)?

More specifically, I don't see any spells that supply bonus threat generation like I am used to with other classes, so how do I deal with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite a short answer as you don't have many skills at level 15.
First off: There is no bonus threat anymore. It's now passive for all tank specializations. Monks used to have *Dizzying Haze* for that, but it was removed in Legion.

1. Whenever it's ready use **Keg Smash**
2. Use **Chi Burst** or **Chi Wave** if you used one of these as level 15 talent
3. When Keg Smash and your lvl 15 skill  are not up use **Blackout Strike**
4. When they all are not up or you're out of energy use **Tiger Palm**

Your taunt is **Provoke**. Use that on bosses or other mobs that are out of melee range. Use **Roll** to get to the mobs faster when your taunt is on cooldown or you need it for another mob.

With higher level it will be easier to keep aggro. You'll get more skills as you level up.

- *Crackling Jade Lightning* at lvl 18 is a good range skill
- *Chi Torpedo* (lvl 30 talent) is quite useful in dungeons
- *Breath of Fire* at lvl 40 is a decent AoE skill that helps a lot keeping mob groups aggro

Especially in low level dungeons the damage dealers are often reckless and pull too many mobs or just attack the boss without you being ready. If they die, it's their own fault (and as a tank I might just then take a 10 seconds coffee break when someone keeps pulling mobs without my permission).